# Why does a return statement on a new line not return any value?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following case:

```
function func1() {
  return {
      hello: "world"
  };
}

function func2() {
  return
  {
      hello: "world"
  };
}

console.log(func1());
console.log(func2());
```

The first function `func1()` will return the object `{ hello: "world" }` but the second function `func2()` will return `undefined`. **Why is that?** My guess is the returned value needs to be on the same line as the `return` keyword. What "rule" am I unaware of here?

Comment: [Semicolon insertion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "rule" is [automatic semicolon insertion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion).

`return` is a valid statement all on its own, so it is treated as a complete statement. The code starting on the next line is also syntactically valid (although it's not interpreted as an object at all in this case, but rather a code block containing a label and a single "statement" that consists of a string literal). So automatic semicolon insertion kicks in here and the two are treated as separate statements.

The code that starts on the line after the `return` is simply ignored.

Note that some IDEs and linters can help with this, since you essentially have unreachable code. Here is a screenshot of how VSCode's default syntax highlighting displays the two functions. You can see that the `hello: world` is shaded a dull color in the second function:

[image: Screenshot of VSCode showing unreachable code.]

Comment: This might be helpful too [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion)

Answer (score 2):

It's because of automatic semicolon insertion. The JS engine is thinking you left out a semicolon on a blank `return;` statement and "helpfully" inserting it for you.

Other than removing the newline, you can also fix this by putting parentheses around the `{..}`, the first one on the same line as the `return`.