# Vue only works when I put braces next to return

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm starting with Vue and I'm trying to understand why this code works

```
<!-- HTML element -->
<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
<!-- Script for our app -->
<script>

    const { createApp }     =   Vue

    createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                message     :   'Hello Vue'
            }
        }
    }).mount( '#app' )
</script>
```

and this one doesn't.

```
<!-- HTML element -->
<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
<!-- Script for our app -->
<script>

    const { createApp }     =   Vue

    createApp({
        data() {
            return 
            {
                message     :   'Hello Vue'
            }
        }
    }).mount( '#app' )
</script>
```

Note that I only did a line jump after the return and now it doesn't work. Is it a syntax related problem?

Comment: There's an implied semi-colon after the return on its own line.  Probably a dup of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154203/why-does-a-return-statement-on-a-new-line-not-return-any-value (which is itself a dup, but IMO has a clearer answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a return statement on a new line not return any value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154203/why-does-a-return-statement-on-a-new-line-not-return-any-value)